# I need to change the content of a web page without refreshing where the change happens in the server side

Tags: java, ajax

I have a web app with java that take requests from clients, process the request then send the result back to the client. I want to add a graphic interface that will show information about the request, the process and the result after the arrival of each request. I want to do this without having the page reloading, the server can receive a lot of requests in a short time so reloading the page is not a good solution. I've tried doing this with AJAX but the change is after an event provoked at the client side, for example a click on a button. I want the event to be on the server's side my event needs to be the arrival of a new request. tried using setInterval but the result is not what I expect, its like only one request get shown out of 10 
this is the setInterval code :

```
setInterval(function() { 
    $.get("log", function(responseText) {
        $("#container").append(responseText + "<br>");
    });
}, 10);
```

log is the URL of the servlet that gives information about the request 
the doGet methode of the log servlet :

```java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(requestInfo);
}
```

every time a request arrive I start putting information in requestInfo

Comment: the webpage is on client side. how do you assume to update that without some action on the client side?

Comment: If the server needs to push information to the client without being requested by the client then the technology you're looking for is probably Web Sockets.

Comment: @Stultuske exactly what i was thinking, I was looking if there is a way for the client to stay connected tel the server notify the client that a change happened, I'm going to take David's way and look for a solution with web sockets thank you both for your response

Answer (score 0):

If you want to constantly check the status, you have to recall your ajax function. If you want to be informed by push, you have to use websockets.

```
function checkLog(){
$.get("log", function(responseText) {
        var $notFinished = true;
        console.log('fetch from server')
        $("#container").append(responseText + "<br>");


        // do some checks to determine server has finished, set notFinished to false if it is your last ajax request
        ...

        if($notFinished){
          // recall the function in 10 seconds for status check
          setInterval(function() { 
            checkLog();
          }, 10000);
        }
    });
}

// call the function the first time
checkLog();
```

Comment: I think web sockets well be the better solution checking constantly if a change happened or not is just to much work better that the server takes control. thank you for your response

Comment: Yes, websocket can be a good way, but not on every hosting this is possible, as far as i know.